# Visual Studio does not find form1.vb unless in specific folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm a novice VB and Visual Studio amateur user. I've been developing app in VS 2019 for a while with no problems. Project is stored on my google drive in a folder named "source". Recently upgraded computer, reinstalled VS 2019 and mapped google drive back in and copied "source" back. Now when I load my project, I get an error that form1.vb is not found. app has 4 forms. All of the other forms show up. Looking at the error log and properties it appears that "google drive"  is added the path for the file ":g\google drive\source\repo\myapp\". Even if a copy the folder to another location it keeps looking for "google drive". IE: "new location\google drive\form1.vb" If I create a folder named "google drive" and drop in form1.vb it loads. I can't figure out where the appendage is coming from or how to fix it.

Comment: Try to click 'File' ->'Open' -> 'Project/Solution..' in your Visual Studio, then select your project in File Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution but not the cause.
Copied source folder to new location, deleted "form1". Then copied "form1" back in from the old non working folder. It loads as expected.

Comment: Please consider [accepting your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)